# jQuery.position() left issue

Tags: jquery, position

I was reading about the jQuery.position() document [here](http://api.jquery.com/position/), the example code prints `position.left` = 15 while when I tested the same code at codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Huxbr) (both on chrome and firefox) it prints 23. It seems that the `<body>` has 8px margins, and it adds to the 15px padding in the `<div>`, and it results 23px. But as the official document says, this function "retrieve the current position of an element **relative to the offset parent**", then why those major browser output 23 instead of 18?

example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>position demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  p {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<p></p>

<script>
var p = $( "p:first" );
var position = p.position();
$( "p:last" ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try one thing that apply position relative to parent div then check I think it will help you

Comment: Can you please share your HTML and css so I can try to investigate

Comment: @YogeshSharma shouldn't position() already does the business, as the doc says it "retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8J2bW/1/  check this fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like when playing around with "position: absolute" items and trying to position them, the offset parent is not the direct parent. It walks up the dom until it finds parent which is *not* in default layout-mode. Using any non-static position on the parent will set this as offset-container for your element.

In your example there weren't any offset parents in non-static mode so it took the body as parent.

As Yogesh Sharma suggested: setting the following should help:

```
div {position:relative;}
```